# How to add an tree view inside a notbook form in odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

i want to add an tree view in a custom module like this :
[image]

this is my XML File :
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mahmoud,
For the notebook need a `One2many` field in main class to the notebook's class and need a `Many2one` field from notebook's class to the main class. And add that One2many field in the xml before the tree tag.

For example:

```
class Mainclass(models.Model):
_name = 'main.class'
    notebook_ids = fields.One2many('notebook.class', 'main_class_id', string="Notebook")


class NotebookClass(models.Model):
_name = 'notebook.class'
      main_class_id = fields.Many2one('main.class', string="Main Class")
      name = fields.Char(string="Name")
      state = fields.Char(string="state")
```

In the XML you have to add,

```
<notebook>
    <page>
        <field name="notebook_ids">
            <tree>
                <field name="name"/>
                <field name="state"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </page>
</notebook>
```

Add One2many field on wherever you need to add a notebook. And notebook field's should be written in an another class.

Thanks in advance ! Happy Coding !

Answer (score 1):

For that you will need to define a field of type One2many or Many2many to be able to show it as a tree view relation in your form. You could have nested the `<tree/>` definition of your o2m or m2m field with the  fields to show from the relation model nested in your field, like:

```
<notebook>
    <page>
        <field name="x2m_field">
            <tree>
                <field name="name"/>
                <field name="state"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </page>
</notebook>
```

I didn't have used exactly your view definition because images cannot be copied into gedit, but you could get the idea from the example

Comment: please what is the value that should a write it  instead of "x2m_field" ? any x2m field or what ?

Comment: the name of a relational field in the model of the main form that will contain the field relation between your main form model which is `contrat.contrat` and the `new model` that will save the values of the tree lines.